# Json data is saved differently depending on local or root filepath

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've created a simple class that writes and reads json data with a txt file:

```
 using System;
 using System.IO;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
 
 namespace JsonTest1
 {
     class Program
     {
         private const string filePath = @"..\jsonData.txt";

         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             JsonFileTest();
             NewPerson();
             DeSerializer();
             Console.ReadLine();
         }
 
         //Tests if the project's storage file exists.
         public static void JsonFileTest()
         {
             bool exists = File.Exists(filePath);
 
             if (exists)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("File exists at filepath " + filePath);
             }
             else
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(filePath + " not found.");
             }
         }
 
         //Creates a test object of 'Person' then passes it to the serializer method.
         public static void NewPerson()
         {
             Person person = new Person();
             person.Name = "John Wick";
             person.Age = 999;
             SerializeMethod(person);
         }
 
         //Turns an object into JSON data and writes it to file.
         static void SerializeMethod(Person person)
         {
             File.WriteAllText(filePath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person));
             Console.WriteLine("Test name and age copied to file.");
         }
 
         //Turns JSON data from file into an object.
         static void DeSerializer()
         {
             Person person2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
             if (person2 != null)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Json-to-C# test data: " + person2.Name + ", " + person2.Age);
             }
             else
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("No data received for json-to-C# test object.");
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

The issue is, if I set filePath to be something like `@"C:\Users\User\Documents\json.txt"`, then it will create a text file that I can see the data in afterwards. If `filePath` is local, e.g. `@"..\jsonData.txt"`, I open the file and it's empty, even though my program can read correctly from it at runtime. Why isn't the data saving when I use the local file route?

Things I've already tried: Using a `.json` file instead of a `.txt` file. Running Visual Studio as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking in the wrong folder. Your program will be executed from the `bin\debug` folder or something. `..` then is the `bin` folder.

A general approach for resolving "file not found" problems is to use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), a free program. Add a filter with the properties `Path`, `contains`, `jsonData.txt`, click <kbd>Add</kbd> and then let your program run.

[image: Path contains filter]

This will reveal the full path:

[image: Results]

Then click on `Jump to...` in the context menu to reveal that path.

[image: Jump to]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the full path for any path expression like this

```
var fp = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\jsonData.txt");
```